# to execute js in objective c

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

I need to communicate the with code http://code.kwint.in/emoji/source/. I have written  code to get iPhone emoji to web view (editor) but it do not show emoji except square box with question mark, indicating there is no image. So i found the above link. How do i communicate with this. I had my js file.

```
 -(void)imageToTextViewForHome:(id)sender
{
UIButton *refrenceButtonForHome;
refrenceButtonForHome = sender;
int tag  = refrenceButtonForHome.tag;
NSLog(@"tag...%d",tag);
NSString *imageNameToPass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[emoticonsArrayForHomeEmoji 
objectAtIndex:tag]];
NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageNameToPass ofType:@"png"];
NSLog(@"pathForImage..%@",path);
[webViewForEditing stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"document.execCommand('insertImage', false, '%@')", path]];
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You can use emoticons just fine using their unicode representation.

Comment: @Eiko I have a webview which accept image return by java script. And i can insert image any where ib between text. Thats why i need that code to convert it into .png formant.

Answer (score 1):

A webview can run javascript, but I guess you're not able to return something directly.

Take a look at the example below:

http://will.thimbleby.net/script/